# Почему порядок строк так важен?

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, scanf

Только приступил к изучению C (опыт в программировании мал), попалась такая задача: *Необходимо переключить 3 и 0 биты переменной bits. Результат сохраните в байтовой беззнаковой переменной res и выведите ее значение в консоль в виде целого десятичного числа.* Моя программа выглядит таким образом:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    unsigned char bits;
    unsigned char mask = 0b1001;
    scanf("%hhd", &bits);
    printf("%u", mask ^ bits);
    return 0;
}
```

Но по сути всегда выводится значение `bits`, а не `mask ^ bits`. Но если строчку `scanf("%hhd", &bits);` поменять местами с `unsigned char mask = 0b1001;`, то все будет работать. Либо я чего-то не понимаю, либо что-то не так с компилятором (хотя трудно себе это представить). Кстати, стандарт языка C99, и компилятор MinGW32. Вдруг, это важно.. Кстати, на самом Stepik`е все работает во обеих вариациях.

Comment: *"выводится значение bits, а не mask ^ bits"* - слабое заявление, я его [проверил](https://godbolt.org/z/3bzfdfYed) Убедитесь, что у себя не забыли пересобрать программу перед запуском.

Comment: У меня выводится именно `bits` . Я и так догадываюсь, что проблема не в синтаксисе.. Я пересобирал десятки раз))

Comment: Возможно в вашем случае при вводе данных черех scanf переписывается значение в mask. Попробуйте так же вывести и значение mask

Comment: У меня проблема не наблюдается, ввожу 0 — получаю 9 как и должно

Comment: Старые версии MSVCRT не поддерживают модификатор длины `hh`. См. [Why is `scanf("%hhu", char*)` overwriting other variables when they are local?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15825254)

Comment: @wololo *"стандарт языка C99, и компилятор MinGW32"*

Comment: @user7860670 Какую мысль хотите донести? Что MinGW32 не использует MSVCRT, или что MSVCRT гарантированно поддерживает модификатор `hh`? Или что-то иное?